# Wordpress: Redirect user after commenting

Tags: wordpress, redirect, comments

I'm trying to redirect users after commenting on my Wordpress blog, can anyone steer me into the right direct? I just want it to redirect them once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can do this. The first and simplest is just to write a little function for yourself to do it. You could put this into your functions.php file, in whatever theme you are using.

```
add_action('comment_post_redirect', 'your_redirect_function');

// A function that redirects your users after they have commented.
function your_redirect_function ($location, $comment) {
    // Here all you need to do is return the url of your target page.
    $page = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
    return $page;
}
```

Sometimes it's better to use Wordpress plugins rather than adding functions to your theme's functions.php file, because if your theme has an update then you'll lose your function! There are some plugins available to do this - the most popular one is Yoast's (he has a plugin for everything doesn't he?) You can download it at http://wordpress.org/plugins/comment-redirect/

I've found Yoast's plugin to be a little limited though, because the redirect will only work once for each of your users. This is a good and bad thing - say you want to thank your user for a comment, then you can only do it once. But it's good if you're asking them to sign up to a service, say. The other popular comment redirect plugin that has more features (but it's not free unfortunately) is [Comment Redirect](http://www.commentredirect.com).

Again, it's probably better to go for a plugin, because it will have more features - like limiting the number of times each user gets redirected - and it will also survive the updates to your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below filter hook

```
comment_post_redirect
```

For more details
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

More samples below:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/a-simple-redirect-using-comment_post_redirect-in-functionsphp

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirect-after-posting-a-comment